# KLX230 Check Engine Light After Stall

Tags: motorcycle

I've had this bike (2020 KLX230), brand new for about two weeks now, I just now stalled it for my first time at a light (embarrassing), and the check engine light came on, once I started it back up and got going again, it never went off, and still hasn't gone off, What can I check or do at this point? Do I need to reset it or something?